# "The name 'Drive' does not exist in it's current form" - And some other problems C#

Tags: c#

Getting afew errors here which I need explaining to me. Here is my code, I have added comments with the error number next to some of the code:

```
namespace JamSnaps
{
    class Functions
    {
         public void GetConnectedDevices(ref string[] ConnectedDrives) {
            //Put all connected drives into an array
            System.IO.DriveInfo[] myDrives = System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives();

            foreach (System.IO.DriveInfo info in myDrives)
            {
                if (info.DriveType == System.IO.DriveType.Removable && info.IsReady)
                {
                    //textBox1.Text += info.Name + info.VolumeLabel + "\r\n";
                    //Create array with connected drives and information
                    string[] Drives = new string[] 
                    {
                        info.Name,
                        info.VolumeLabel,
                        info.TotalFreeSpace.ToString(),
                        info.TotalSize.ToString()
                    };
                    //[0] Drive Letter
                    //[1] Drive Name
                    //[2] Free Space
                    //[3] Total Size
                }
            }
            if (Drives.Count > 0)  //1
            {
                ConnectedDrives = Drive; //2
            }
            else 
            {
                ConnectedDrives = false; //3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. The name 'Drives' does not exist in the current context
2. The name 'Drives' does not exist in the current context
3. Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string[]'

More errors on a button i'm trying to call the function with:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] drives;
            JamSnaps.Functions.GetConnectedDevices(ref drives); //4

            MessageBox.Show(drives);

        }
```

4: The best overloaded method match for 'JamSnaps.Functions.GetConnectedDevices(ref string[])' has some invalid arguments

Theres more but lets get these fixed first.

EDIT

That makes sense now thanks Cyral, one more question, what am I doing wrong here?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] ConnectedDrives;
            JamSnaps.Functions.GetConnectedDevices(ref ConnectedDrives);
        }
```

I'm defining the array ready, then the ref should replace that array with new data?

I don't get this scope thing, in PHP I would be able to use the [icode]Drives [/icode] from the IF statement outside of it (if the if statement was executed of course)

Comment: I see that issue now, I will simply keep it empty instead. What about the other issues ?

Comment: Your question shows a complete lack of understanding of basic coding principles, eg scope, variables and types for a start.  Learn these and you will know how to fix the code.

Comment: And it's no surprise to see you do not know how to properly call a method either.

Comment: @JK. Gotta learn somehow... Will get my hands on a C# Programming book though, I prefer to learn through trial and error sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access `Drives` because it is in a different scope. I think you are looking for `myDrives` instead.'

`ConnectedDrives` is a string array, and therefor cannot hold boolean values. In this case, you should handle the exception accordingly if the drive count is 0. (Or leave it set to `null`)

For your final error, make sure you initialize your `string[] drives` with `= new string[0]`

**However...**
I think you are trying to get a list of all the drives, and in thise case there will only ever be one because your code recreates the `Drives` array on each iteration.

You should add each drive that matches your criteria to a list, and return that instead.

```
public void GetConnectedDevices(ref System.IO.DriveInfo[] ConnectedDrives)
{
    //Put all connected drives into an array
    System.IO.DriveInfo[] myDrives = System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives();

    List<System.IO.DriveInfo> Drives = new List<System.IO.DriveInfo>();

    foreach (System.IO.DriveInfo info in myDrives)
    {
        if (info.DriveType == System.IO.DriveType.Removable && info.IsReady)
        {
            Drives.Add(info);
        }
    }
    if (Drives.Count > 0)  //1
    {
        ConnectedDrives = Drives.ToArray<System.IO.DriveInfo>();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I can't tell you the exact reason, but in C# you need to initialize your variables before passing them using `ref`. In this case using my code above, use:

```
List<System.IO.DriveInfo> ConnectedDrives = new List<System.IO.DriveInfo>();
JamSnaps.Functions.GetConnectedDevices(ref ConnectedDrives);
```

You really don't need to use `ref`, you could simply have your method return a `List<System.IO.DriveInfo>` instead of `void` because you do not need to pass anything to the method:

```
public List<System.IO.DriveInfo> GetConnectedDevices()
...
if (Drives.Count > 0)  //1
{
    return Drives;
}
```

And in your button method:

```
List<System.IO.DriveInfo> ConnectedDrives = JamSnaps.Functions.GetConnectedDevices();
```

Comment: Getting this error now: `'JamSnaps.Functions.GetConnectedDevices()': not all code paths return a value` which is highlighting this: `public List<System.IO.DriveInfo> GetConnectedDevices()`